# Excel - is there a BUT function?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am currently trying to figure out a formula; I have the following: `=IF(G18>109,"A*",IF(G18>103,"A",IF(G18>85,"B",IF(G18>67,"C","F"))))`

This allows me to work out grades for my students in my French class but I want to add another part to the formula... I want it so that if `C18:F18` says "INC", then the cell this formula is in says "inc" for an incomplete course.

Is that possible?

Comment: Just add another IF clause, but what does "if C18:F18 says "INC"" mean? Every cell, one cell?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following formula:

`=IF(G15="INC","inc",IF(G15>109,"A*",IF(G15>103,"A",IF(G15>85,"B",IF(G15>67,"C","F")))))`

See attached example image:

[image]

Comment: That only checks `G15` - OP wants to look at columns `C:F`.

Comment: Can put the same formula into a range

Answer (score 0):

This will return INC if one or more cells in C18:F18 contain INC.

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH("INC",C18:F18,0)),IF(G18>109,"A*",IF(G18>103,"A",IF(G18>85,"B",IF(G18>67,"C","F")))),"INC")`

`MATCH("INC",C18:F18,0)` will return the position of the first occurrence of INC, or `#N/A` if it's not there.